# meson: copy a symlink as is instead of copy file

Tags: meson-build

I want to use meson with a project that contains symlinks. I am getting this warning:

```
Warning: trying to copy a symlink that points to a file. This will copy the file,
but this will be changed in a future version of Meson to copy the symlink as is. Please update your
build definitions so that it will not break when the change happens.
```

Is there an option to copy symlink files as is now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's now `install_symlink` method.

A way to preserve the current directory structure is to use stuff like

```
local_links = run_command(
    'find',
    dir,
    '-type', 'l',
    '-maxdepth', '1,
  ).stdout().strip().split('\n')
```

And then iterate through `local_links` using `readlink` to see the target and eventually installing them as they are.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no stable feature for copying symlinks in Meson, I'd open a bug/feature request for that.